# PicklingError: Could not pickle the task to send it to the workers. while using gridsearch for lgbm

Tags: python, machine-learning, grid-search, lightgbm, boosting

I'm trying to find best parameter in LGBM using GridSearch and here's my approach.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
import lightgbm as lgb

model = lgb.LGBMRegressor(random_state=1, objective='regression')
param_grid = {
        'max_depth':[20, 30, 2],
        'num_leaves': [700, 1000, 100],
        'min_data_in_leaf': range(200, 500),
        'n_estimators': [400, 800, 100],
        'learning_rate':[0.05],
        'feature_fraction':[0.4, 0.5],
        'max_bin':[400, 500]}

model_l = GridSearchCV(model, param_grid, cv=5 , n_jobs=-1)

model_l.fit(df_train_robust, y_floor_train, 
             eval_set=[(df_test_robust, y_floor_test)], 
             eval_metric=['l1','l2_root','mape'])
```

After running for like a day I'm getting this error:

```
/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/externals/loky/process_executor.py:706: UserWarning: A worker stopped while some jobs were given to the executor. This can be caused by a too short worker timeout or by a memory leak.
  "timeout or by a memory leak.", UserWarning
exception calling callback for <Future at 0x7f2a65498ad0 state=finished raised PicklingError>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 505, in dump
    NumpyPickler(f, protocol=protocol).dump(value)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 437, in dump
    self.save(obj)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 292, in save
    wrapper.write_array(obj, self)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 104, in write_array
    pickler.file_handle.write(chunk.tostring('C'))
OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/externals/loky/backend/queues.py", line 150, in _feed
    obj_ = dumps(obj, reducers=reducers)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/externals/loky/backend/reduction.py", line 247, in dumps
    dump(obj, buf, reducers=reducers, protocol=protocol)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/externals/loky/backend/reduction.py", line 240, in dump
    _LokyPickler(file, reducers=reducers, protocol=protocol).dump(obj)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/externals/cloudpickle/cloudpickle.py", line 482, in dump
    return Pickler.dump(self, obj)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 437, in dump
    self.save(obj)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 549, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 662, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 859, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 885, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 549, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 662, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 859, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 890, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 549, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 662, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 859, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 885, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 819, in save_list
    self._batch_appends(obj)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 846, in _batch_appends
    save(tmp[0])
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 774, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 774, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 549, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 662, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 859, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 885, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 549, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 662, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 789, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 819, in save_list
    self._batch_appends(obj)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 846, in _batch_appends
    save(tmp[0])
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 549, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 638, in save_reduce
    save(args)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 774, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 859, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 885, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 510, in save
    rv = reduce(obj)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/_memmapping_reducer.py", line 339, in __call__
    for dumped_filename in dump(a, filename):
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 505, in dump
    NumpyPickler(f, protocol=protocol).dump(value)
OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/externals/loky/_base.py", line 625, in _invoke_callbacks
    callback(self)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 340, in __call__
    self.parallel.dispatch_next()
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 769, in dispatch_next
    if not self.dispatch_one_batch(self._original_iterator):
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 835, in dispatch_one_batch
    self._dispatch(tasks)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 754, in _dispatch
    job = self._backend.apply_async(batch, callback=cb)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/_parallel_backends.py", line 551, in apply_async
    future = self._workers.submit(SafeFunction(func))
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/externals/loky/reusable_executor.py", line 160, in submit
    fn, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/externals/loky/process_executor.py", line 1047, in submit
    self._ensure_executor_running()
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/externals/loky/process_executor.py", line 1021, in _ensure_executor_running
    self._adjust_process_count()
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/externals/loky/process_executor.py", line 999, in _adjust_process_count
    worker_exit_lock = self._context.BoundedSemaphore(1)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/externals/loky/backend/context.py", line 220, in BoundedSemaphore
    return BoundedSemaphore(value)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/externals/loky/backend/synchronize.py", line 156, in __init__
    SemLock.__init__(self, SEMAPHORE, value, value)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/externals/loky/backend/synchronize.py", line 70, in __init__
    unlink_now)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/externals/loky/backend/queues.py", line 150, in _feed
    obj_ = dumps(obj, reducers=reducers)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 505, in dump
    NumpyPickler(f, protocol=protocol).dump(value)
OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/externals/loky/_base.py", line 625, in _invoke_callbacks
    callback(self)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 340, in __call__
    self.parallel.dispatch_next()
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 769, in dispatch_next
    if not self.dispatch_one_batch(self._original_iterator):
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/externals/loky/backend/synchronize.py", line 156, in __init__
    SemLock.__init__(self, SEMAPHORE, value, value)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/externals/loky/backend/synchronize.py", line 70, in __init__
    unlink_now)
OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device

exception calling callback for <Future at 0x7f2a651b3710 state=finished raised PicklingError>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 505, in dump
    NumpyPickler(f, protocol=protocol).dump(value)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 437, in dump
    self.save(obj)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 292, in save
    wrapper.write_array(obj, self)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 104, in write_array
    pickler.file_handle.write(chunk.tostring('C'))
OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/externals/loky/backend/queues.py", line 150, in _feed
    obj_ = dumps(obj, reducers=reducers)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/externals/loky/backend/synchronize.py", line 156, in __init__
    SemLock.__init__(self, SEMAPHORE, value, value)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/externals/loky/backend/synchronize.py", line 70, in __init__
    unlink_now)
OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device

exception calling callback for <Future at 0x7f2a65158090 state=finished raised PicklingError>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 505, in dump
    NumpyPickler(f, protocol=protocol).dump(value)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 437, in dump
    self.save(obj)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 292, in save
    wrapper.write_array(obj, self)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 104, in write_array
    pickler.file_handle.write(chunk.tostring('C'))
OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/externals/loky/backend/queues.py", line 150, in _feed
    obj_ = dumps(obj, reducers=reducers)
  
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/_memmapping_reducer.py", line 339, in __call__
    for dumped_filename in dump(a, filename):
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 505, in dump
    NumpyPickler(f, protocol=protocol).dump(value)
OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/externals/loky/_base.py", line 625, in _invoke_callbacks
    callback(self)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 340, in __call__
    self.parallel.dispatch_next()
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 769, in dispatch_next
    if not self.dispatch_one_batch(self._original_iterator):
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 835, in dispatch_one_batch
    self._dispatch(tasks)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 754, in _dispatch
    job = self._backend.apply_async(batch, callback=cb)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/_parallel_backends.py", line 551, in apply_async
    future = self._workers.submit(SafeFunction(func))
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/externals/loky/reusable_executor.py", line 160, in submit
    fn, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/externals/loky/process_executor.py", line 1047, in submit
    self._ensure_executor_running()
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/externals/loky/process_executor.py", line 1021, in _ensure_executor_running
    self._adjust_process_count()
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/externals/loky/process_executor.py", line 999, in _adjust_process_count
    worker_exit_lock = self._context.BoundedSemaphore(1)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/externals/loky/backend/context.py", line 220, in BoundedSemaphore
    return BoundedSemaphore(value)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/externals/loky/backend/synchronize.py", line 156, in __init__
    SemLock.__init__(self, SEMAPHORE, value, value)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/externals/loky/backend/synchronize.py", line 70, in __init__
    unlink_now)
OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device

exception calling callback for <Future at 0x7f2a65158310 state=finished raised PicklingError>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/externals/loky/backend/synchronize.py", line 156, in __init__
    SemLock.__init__(self, SEMAPHORE, value, value)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/externals/loky/backend/synchronize.py", line 70, in __init__
    unlink_now)
OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device

exception calling callback for <Future at 0x7f2a651824d0 state=finished raised PicklingError>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 505, in dump
    NumpyPickler(f, protocol=protocol).dump(value)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 437, in dump
    self.save(obj)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 292, in save
    wrapper.write_array(obj, self)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 104, in write_array
    pickler.file_handle.write(chunk.tostring('C'))
OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:


    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 662, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 859, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 885, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 549, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 662, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 789, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 819, in save_list
    self._batch_appends(obj)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 846, in _batch_appends
    save(tmp[0])
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 549, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 638, in save_reduce
    save(args)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 774, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 859, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 885, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 510, in save
    rv = reduce(obj)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/_memmapping_reducer.py", line 339, in __call__
    for dumped_filename in dump(a, filename):
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 505, in dump
    NumpyPickler(f, protocol=protocol).dump(value)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 437, in dump
    self.save(obj)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 292, in save
    wrapper.write_array(obj, self)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 104, in write_array
    pickler.file_handle.write(chunk.tostring('C'))
OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

PicklingError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-ad2cda3e0f98> in <module>
      1 gs_m2_rs_poly.fit(df_train_robust, y_floor_train, 
      2              eval_set=[(df_test_robust, y_floor_test)],
----> 3              eval_metric=['l1','l2_root','mape'])

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py in fit(self, X, y, groups, **fit_params)
    708                 return results
    709 
--> 710             self._run_search(evaluate_candidates)
    711 
    712         # For multi-metric evaluation, store the best_index_, best_params_ and

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py in _run_search(self, evaluate_candidates)
   1149     def _run_search(self, evaluate_candidates):
   1150         """Search all candidates in param_grid"""
-> 1151         evaluate_candidates(ParameterGrid(self.param_grid))
   1152 
   1153 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py in evaluate_candidates(candidate_params)
    687                                for parameters, (train, test)
    688                                in product(candidate_params,
--> 689                                           cv.split(X, y, groups)))
    690 
    691                 if len(out) < 1:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py in __call__(self, iterable)
   1015 
   1016             with self._backend.retrieval_context():
-> 1017                 self.retrieve()
   1018             # Make sure that we get a last message telling us we are done
   1019             elapsed_time = time.time() - self._start_time

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py in retrieve(self)
    907             try:
    908                 if getattr(self._backend, 'supports_timeout', False):
--> 909                     self._output.extend(job.get(timeout=self.timeout))
    910                 else:
    911                     self._output.extend(job.get())

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/_parallel_backends.py in wrap_future_result(future, timeout)
    560         AsyncResults.get from multiprocessing."""
    561         try:
--> 562             return future.result(timeout=timeout)
    563         except LokyTimeoutError:
    564             raise TimeoutError()

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/_base.py in result(self, timeout)
    426                 raise CancelledError()
    427             elif self._state == FINISHED:
--> 428                 return self.__get_result()
    429 
    430             self._condition.wait(timeout)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/_base.py in __get_result(self)
    382     def __get_result(self):
    383         if self._exception:
--> 384             raise self._exception
    385         else:
    386             return self._result

PicklingError: Could not pickle the task to send it to the workers.
```

I don't know what's going wrong after running for a while, initially I might be running out of storage so I increased the size of the instance but still running into same thing. Is it because I have too many parameter to train. I have around 1.6 million records for training this with 40 variables. Or is there a better way to find hyper parameter?

Instance:

```
ubuntu 20.04
m5a.8Xlarge
1000GB
```

Answer (score -3):

I had the same problem.

I don't know why, but setting n_jobs=1 works to me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31162545)

Comment: While technically solving the problem, one also tanks the performance by disabling parallelization with your solution.